# Dynamically change paper size based on printer being displayed on NSPrintPanel

Tags: cocoa, printing, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

We are trying to modify the default selected paper size for a NSPrintPanel. Using NSNotification we are able to observe and implement changes on our  accessoryViews in the NSPrintPanel. However when we try to implement `setPaperSize` (NSPrintInfo the instance method), nothing happens and the initial paper size (default) for the default printer is selected for all other printers (We have regular printers and receipt printers).

I know the new paper size being set is correct whenever the printer changes. We are programmatically obtaining the paper sizes from the Core Print. While trying to the set the right/desired paperSize, the app doesn't break or returns any stack. So it seems, it seems apple doesn't support changes to the paper size PrintPanel.

While researching the issue, we noticed that NSPrintPanel accessory view from apple titled "Paper Handling" seems to respond to the printer changes, based on the settings you provide to Page Setup (in the file menu, NSPageLayout). So our questions are:

1. Is there a way to access/set the Suggested Paper size displayed in this accessoryView programmatically?
2. I know this accessoryView reads from page setup (NSPageLayout), thus I'd like to know if to access set these values in the "Paper Handling" accessoryView is a good approach?

Notes:
- Mac doesn't seem to allow/provide a user friendly way to set default paper sizes for each printer installed.

Accessory View we are talking about:
[image: Accessory View that we not able to modify]

We have reviewed apple documentation (of course) and posting from other people with similar issues with no avail. We'd greatly appreciate a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which printInfo are you calling setPaperSize: on?

Comment: @WilShipley I am calling it, this way:
`[[mPrintOperation printInfo] setPaperSize: [aSizeValue sizeValue]];`

Answer (score 0):

It’s been a while since I’ve done this, but what happens when you set it on the NSPrintPanel’s printInfo? Any better? It might make its own temporary copy.